# How to count words on each line of input in C

Tags: c, string

Im trying to make a program so it counts the words on each line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM_LINES 50

int main()
{
char text[NUM_LINES];
int count = 0;
int nw = 0;
char *token;
char *space = " ";
printf("Enter the text:\n");

while (fgets(text, NUM_LINES, stdin)){

    token = strtok(text, space);

    while (token != NULL){

        if (strlen(token) > 0){
            ++nw;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }


    if (strcmp(text , "e") == 0 || strcmp(text , "e\n") == 0){
        break;
    }


}
printf("%d words", nw-1);

return 0;
}
```

For example if the input is:

```
Hello my name is John
I would like to have a snack
I like to play tennis
e
```

My program outputs the total words (17 in this case) how do I count the words on each line individually. So the output I would want is "5 7 5" in this example.

Comment: Code fails to count correctly if there is a space after the last word and before the `'\n'`.

Comment: I don't need it to do that i just want to get it to work. I'm don't care about those kinds of errors right now

Answer (score 4):

> How do I count the words on each line individually?

Simply add a local counter `line_word_count`.

Suggest expanding the delimiter list to cope with spaces after the last word.

```
char *space = " \r\n";

while (fgets(text, NUM_LINES, stdin)){
    int line_word_count = 0;
    token = strtok(text, space);
    while (token != NULL){
        if (strlen(token) > 0){
            line_word_count++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }
    if (strcmp(text , "e") == 0 || strcmp(text , "e\n") == 0){
        break;
    }
    printf("%d ", line_word_count);
    nw += line_word_count; 
}
printf("\n%d words\n", nw);
```

Comment: I dont see how this works because it's printing the total amount of words  still (the last print statement). Also, you put the print statement in the while loop so that it just prints everytime I press enter. I need it to print out at the very end-(see what I wrote for my example)

Comment: Sorry but this answer was no help at all

Comment: @JohnSmith Save line count results in an array `int line_count[1000];` and print the results at the end.  My testing piped in the input and so the output was not interlaced with input.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how I would store the results into an array?

Comment: Based upon your [9+ C posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5468887+%5Bc%5D), certainly you all ready can handle storing the results in an array. I am unclear as to the difficulty other than a request for a complete code solution.  Neither am I motivated given the  comments [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706745/how-to-count-words-on-each-line-of-input-in-c/41706949#comment70609376_41706745)  [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706745/how-to-count-words-on-each-line-of-input-in-c/41706949#comment70610313_41706949)